# Lisp pass evaluated expression to macro

Tags: lisp, elisp

I've got an issue where I've got a macro, isentropic expansion which then calls solve-format replacing NIL in a list with 'x?, which then returns a valid expression can be passed to solve.

```
(isentropic-expansion 295 nil 1 4.2 1.4)
```

returns

```
(-
(expt
  (/ 4.2 1)
  (/
   (- 1.4 1)
   1.4))
 (/ x\? 295))
```

which is the valid expression to then put into the solve function

but if I do the following (let's imagine I've set the output from the above command to the variable expr

```
(solve expr 2)
```

the macro doesn't replace the expression symbols with the value of expr, just expr the string, and I get

```
 Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil expr), 1
```

I think this is because I don't fully understand macros yet! Can anyone explain why this is please?

```
(defun newton-f (func x0)
    "Solve the equation FUNC(x)=0 using Newton's method.
  X0 is an initial guess."
  (let* ((tolerance 1e-6)
     (x x0)
     (dx 1e-6)
     fx fpx)
    (while (> (abs (funcall func x)) tolerance)
       (setq fx (funcall func x)
         fpx (/ (- (funcall func (+ x dx)) (funcall func (- x dx))) (* 2 dx))
         x (- x (/ fx fpx))))
    x))
(defmacro solve (expression guess)
  `(newton-f
     (lambda ,(cl-loop for item in (flatten expression)
            if (and (symbolp item) (s-ends-with? "?" (symbol-name item)))
            collect item)
       ,expression)
     ,guess))

(defun solve-format (exp)
  (cond ((null exp) 'x?)
    ((atom exp) exp)
    ((list exp) (cons (solve-format (car exp))
              (if (cdr exp)
                  (solve-format (cdr exp))
                nil)))
    (t (print "what"))))

(defmacro isentropic-expansion (t01 t02 p01 p02 gamma)
  `(solve-format '(- (expt (/ ,p02 ,p01) (/ (- ,gamma 1) ,gamma)) (/ ,t02 ,t01))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`solve` is also a macro:

```
(defmacro solve (expression guess) ...)
```

As macros do not automatically *evaluate* their arguments, when you use this:

```
(solve expr 2)
```

During the macro's expansion it has `expression` bound to the symbol `expr` and `guess` bound to the number `2`.

The `(lambda nil expr)` in the error message is this call:

```el
(lambda ,(cl-loop for item in (flatten expression)
                  if (and (symbolp item) (s-ends-with? "?" (symbol-name item)))
                  collect item)
  ,expression)
```

Comment: Ah - thanks for the explanation. Is there a way to evaluate an expression and then pass it to a macro please?

Comment: Can you *guarantee* that the argument should be evaluated?  What if you were passing the original expression, rather than a variable symbol holding that expression as a value?  If it's a "sometimes, but not always" situation, what is the logic for deciding?

Comment: And note that if you *always* want to evaluate the argument, then using a macro *may* have been a mistake.  Normal functions evaluate their arguments by default.